How to select and join a table with its foreign lists in Querydsl Blaze Persistence Java
I have an entity A with two fields: List<B> and List<C>.
I am trying to perform a select * from A left join with B and C. However, as I am executing this Querydsl task I am getting the MultipleBagFetchException from Hibernate.
    new BlazeJPAQuery(this.entityManager, this.criteriaBuilderFactory)
            .select(QA)
            .from(QA, QA)
            .leftJoin(QA.Bs, QB).fetchJoin()
            .leftJoin(QA.Cs, QC).fetchJoin()
            .fetch()

I have to SELECT hundred of thousands of rows from my database, so if JPA is afterwards invoking a select per. entry to grab additional information it is slowing down everything drastically. I need to do it in a single query if possible.
I have tried:

Creating a subQuery that would grab my Bs and Cs and then doing a leftJoin on that. This does not throw any exception but the values are still not actually part of the generated SELECT statement. They only appear as left join B on A.key = B.key etc.
Tried using a leftJoin(QA.Bs, QB).on(QB.a.key.eq(QA.key).fetchJoin() but again, this does not change the SELECT statement and thus no value is actually retrieved from the database. Hibernate will just detect when I access the values and then perform a SELECT later on.
Tried setting the fetch types to EAGER on the fields, but this just causes Hibernate to fetch them BEFORE I access them and AFTER the main query that grabs all As.
Changing the field types from List to Set and while this does actually work I am concerned about sacrificing pagination that was previously done on the database level, but would now be done on the application level by using set.
Tried creating a subQuery to grab all Bs and Cs and then on application level join them together with the result from my initial query that grabbed all As. This could work, but I rather have one single query.
Other small tweaks here and there to try and solve the issue.

